# Export textures as a flat image with multiple materials

Tags: materials, uv, export, image

I am trying to get a flat texture image, something like this ...

[image]

instead of using multiple textures with a mtl. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

1. You will need to uv unwrap your model first.
2. Apply mulitiple material as you would previously.
3. Set your materials to shadeless or set the bake to only diffuse bake.
4. Bake the information out using your UV unwrap data into a single texture image.

[image]

[image]